# UILabel Autoshrink does not work correctly in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

i think autoshrink in iOS 15 does not work correctly.

my label is `رقم الجواز السفر...`. when i set it to `Minimum Font Scale` or `Minimum Font Size`, it reduce size of font while it has enough space

[image]

with these params, my label looks like this:

[image]

when i see label is view debug hierarchy, it is:

[image]

now i change autoshrink to `Fixed Font Size`:

[image]

so with that everything is ok but with `minimum...` it causes problem

note: i don't have any problem in iOS 14 and 13 and 12 and also in English version of app

Comment: I guess you need to set width or (left and right) constraints to your label

Comment: it has. it is in stackview

Comment: in debug hierarchy it shown that has no constraints